# How many $6$ digit numbers are there whose digits sum to $51$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $6$ digit numbers are there  whose digits sum to $51$?  Permutation and not combination right?  Is the solution $6!/5! + 6!/4! + 6!/(3!3!) = 56$  ways

Comment: Why do you think that's the answer?

Comment: Have you tried just listing them out and checking?  If that's too much, try with a smaller number (or use a computer.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange! What have you tried? Why do you think that your answer is correct? It's easier to guide you when we have a general idea about these sorts of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
$$
51=9+9+9+9+9+6
$$

here the number of permutations are $6$ since we can put the lonely $6$ into $6$ different positions. (or you could think of it as $\frac{6!}{5!\cdot 1!}=6$)

Furthermore

$$
51=9+9+9+9+8+7
$$

which gives $6\cdot 5=30$ again by the same argument, also

$$
51=9+9+9+8+8+8
$$

which adds another $\frac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!}=4\cdot 5=20$

So your solutions seems correct, I would call these "permutation with repetition".

**ps**: next time try to add the way you got the solution into your question, the community here will react in a better way then since we are here to learn, think, educate and not simply "checkread" answers :)

Comment: They are called [restricted (weak) compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29): of 51 into 6 parts, each part restricted to $[0,9]$

Comment: @GCab  Thank you! I meant rather the way we permuted the elements. +1 nonetheless

Comment: in that acception would be better "permutations of a multiset"

Answer (score 2):

We know that all the numbers are digits.
$$(9-x_1)+(9-x_2)+(9-x_3)+(9-x_4)+(9-x_5)+(9-x_6)=51$$

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=9\times 6-51=3$$

$$\binom{6+3-1}{6-1}=\binom{8}{5}=56$$

Of course, this only works because the sum is less than $9$.